# returning only the first Value while i am printing a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

Good day,
Could someone assist me with why when I execute the following code I get only one value returned[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

my_list = []
def extract(URL):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    return soup.select("[data-tooltip-phones]")

def transform(data):
    for item in data:
        phone_url = "https://yellowpages.com.eg" + item["data-tooltip-phones"]
        title = item.find_previous(class_="item-title").text
        address = item.find_previous(class_="address-text").text.strip().replace('\n', 
'')
        phones = requests.get(phone_url).json()
    business = {
        'name': title,
        'address': address,
        'telephone': phones
    }
    my_list.append(business)
x = 1
data = extract(f'https://yellowpages.com.eg/en/category/charcoal/p{x}')
transform(data)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: `my_list.append(business)` is not inside the for loop, so it only happens once, after the loop is done.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent the business and append line so it is inside the for loop:

```
for item in data:
        phone_url = "https://yellowpages.com.eg" + item["data-tooltip-phones"]
        title = item.find_previous(class_="item-title").text
        address = item.find_previous(class_="address-text").text.strip().replace('\n', 
'')
        phones = requests.get(phone_url).json()
        business = {
            'name': title,
            'address': address,
            'telephone': phones
        }
        my_list.append(business)
```